# Why can't I see my XML documentation when decompiling using ICSharpCode.Decompiler?

Tags: c#, decompiling, mono.cecil, xml-documentation

I've been looking into decompiling .dlls using ICSharpCode.Decompiler and found some sample code and fingers in the right direction on this thread:

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/00e59445-9f85-4ec5-a04f-9796a72a00a2/library-to-decompile-assembly-to-c

I've copied the code and added set the variable `ShowXmlDocumentation = true` in the `DecompilerSettings`, however I'm still unable to see my documentation.

My source code looks like this:

```
var settings = new DecompilerSettings
{
    FullyQualifyAmbiguousTypeNames = true,
    ShowXmlDocumentation = true
};

const string assemblyName = "Experiments.Decompilation.dll";
var assembly1 = AssemblyDefinition.ReadAssembly(assemblyName);
var decompilerContext = new DecompilerContext(assembly1.MainModule) {Settings = settings};
var decompiler = new AstBuilder(decompilerContext);

decompiler.AddAssembly(assembly1);

var output = new StringWriter();
decompiler.GenerateCode(new PlainTextOutput(output));

var byteArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(output.ToString());
TextReader codeReader = new StreamReader(new MemoryStream(byteArray));
var line = codeReader.ReadToEnd();
```

Yet the variable `line` never has any of the expected XML documentation in it.

I get the full trace of what's in the .dll, for example

```
namespace Experiments.Decompilation
{
    public interface ITest
    {
        long Method();
    }
}
```

But I was expecting the interface method to have the XML docs I defined, a la

```
namespace Experiments.Decompilation
{
    ///<summary>
    ///This is some test documentation
    ///</summary>
    public interface ITest
    {
        long Method();
    }
}
```

But no cookie for me.

Am I missing anything? Do I need to change any other configuration?

If anyone has any ideas on this I'd really appreciate it. I've been wracking my brains and haven't found a solution myself, so here you are SO, please help!

Comment: Did you compile with optimizations turned on?

Comment: Can you include an example of what you're expecting? Not sure you can document a variable within a method with XML, if that's what you're trying to have.

Comment: @KennethK. whatever the default Visual Studio debug compilation is, so I'm guessing the answer to that is no..

Comment: @Pierre-LucPineault update question, cheers for the pointer

Comment: Oh, since you really want the XML doc over the methods, you can use a specialized add-in like [ILSpy](http://ilspy.net/) that supports it out of the box, which you can embed into Visual Studio from [here](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/8ef1d688-f80c-4380-8004-2ec7f814e7de)

Comment: @Pierre-LucPineault that would be an option but I want access to it programmatically, a VS extension isn't an option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because that property doesn't actually *do* anything within the `ICSharpCode.Decompiler` library. It's just there to support projects (like ILSpy) that want to consume the decompiler.

ILSpy, for example, will [check to see](https://github.com/icsharpcode/ILSpy/blob/master/ILSpy/Languages/CSharpLanguage.cs#L219) if the decompiler has the option set; if so, it will look up the appropriate XML file on-disk and parse the XMLDoc strings, and embed them in the final output.

Also, note that the actual .NET assembly doesn't *have* the XMLDoc in it. Visual Studio generates a separate file with that stuff, and if you don't have that, ILSpy won't be able to include XMLDoc even if you ask.

Comment: Thanks Mike - and thanks for the link to the appropriate GitHub piece too. Looks like I'll have to prise that functionality out of ILSpy if I want it.